# Unable to create flat zip file with PHP's ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive, document-root

I'm trying to create a zip file with a flat folder/file structure with PHP ZipArchive that contains two PDF files. So basically both files should be in the root of the zip file. I use the code below to create the zipfile.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip_filename = "zipfile.zip";

if ($zip->open($zip_filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFile("cover_file.pdf", "cover_file.pdf");
$zip->addFile("inlay_file.pdf", "cover_file.pdf");              
$zip->close();
```

Whatever I do, the files are always placed inside a folder with the samen name as the zipfile.

Is there a way to save the files to the root of the zip file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Answer (score 0):

## Worked Fine for Me

### Index.php

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zip->open('zipfile.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE))
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");

$zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'tf is this?');
$zip->close();
```

### Start Webserver

`$ php -S localhost:8000`

Output is zipfile.zip with test.txt at the root.

Folder Structure

```
|--testProject
|----index.php
|----zipfile.zip
```

zipfile.zip

```
|--zipfile.zip
|----test.txt
```

### Example w/ Multiple Files

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zip->open('zipfile.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE))
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");

for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
    $zip->addFromString("test$i.txt", 'tf is this?');

$zip->close();
```

### Outputs

```
|--zipfile.zip
|----text0.txt
|----text1.txt
|----text2.txt
|----text3.txt
|----text4.txt
|----text5.txt
|----text6.txt
```

Notes: This extension has no configuration directives defined in php.ini

*Tested on PHP 5.5.15*

Comment: It works if you add a single file to zip file. As soon as you add more then 1, it creates the folder with the same name as the zip file,

Comment: Not for me...I just added 6 files.